# magento2 frontend customer login two step Authentication

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-login, two-factor-authentication

is there any magento2 frontend customer login two step Authentication available modules or extensions. If there please share.

like gmail login using security code (get Sms)

How we implement in magento2 customer login

can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this freebie https://github.com/juashyam/2-Factor-Authentication.

This will enable 2FA at frontend.

[image]

Comment: thats for admin sessions